# Whats the difference between these two ways to write a method in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

What is the difference between a method declared in a key/value pair and a declarative method in a JavaScript object, in both of these the `this` keyword works

```
let dog = {
    sound: "roof",
    talk: function(){  //<----------Key/Value
        console.log(this.sound)
    }
}

let dog = {
    sound: "roof",
    function talk(){  //<----------Declarative method
        console.log(this.sound)
    }
}
```

Comment: the difference is `ECMAScript 2015`

Comment: The difference is that the second one isn't valid code.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: true - the second one does not require `function` keyword before `talk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say there is no much difference in ES6 they have introduced this feature which is short hand for key value pair see example below.

**In ES 5**

```
var obj = { 
   talk: function(){ }
}
obj.talk() //This how u call
```

**In ES 6**

```
var obj = { 
   talk(){ } // here there is no need to have property name it will take it talk by default in ES6
}
obj.talk() //This how u call
```

And there is no difference in `this` context
If you want to know more about ES6 feature with example here is [link](https://codetower.github.io/es6-features/)

Comment: i don't thin that's a valid syntax

Comment: @JasperBernales please check here https://codetower.github.io/es6-features/#Enhanced%20Object%20Literals

Comment: remove `function` keyword in ES6

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to define methods in object:

```js
let dog = {
  sound: "roof",
  talk() {
    console.log('first way')
  },
  talk2: function() {
    console.log('second way')
  },
  talk3: () => {
    console.log('third way')
  },
  // function talk4 (){}  // this isn't right way
}

dog.talk(); // first way
dog.talk2(); // second way
dog.talk3(); // third way
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

```
let dog = {
    sound: "roof", // Property
    talk: function(){ // methods
        console.log(this.sound)
    }
}
```

The above code block worked as an object and it contains some properties and methods

You can write the code like,

```js
var dog = (function() {
  function dog() {
    this.sound = 'roof' // class variable
  }
  
  dog.prototype.talk = function() {
    console.log(this.sound); // method
  };
  
  return dog;
}());

var obj = new dog();
obj.talk()
```

Hope you understand

Answer (score -4):

there's no difference unless you convert

```
 talk: function(){  //<----------Key/Value
   console.log(this.sound)
 }
```

to

```
 talk: () => {
    console.log(this.sound)
 }
```

Arrow function uses lexical `this` which means it uses the context where the object is defined in this case `window`. `function` uses the object's context

Comment: the question has nothing to do with `=>` notation

Answer (score -4):

in first case you can use that function in any class and this will point to that class sound
while in second object will access it's object variable that is sound